# What are the differences between GNG and RNNs?

Tags: neural-networks

I'm interested in the differences of RNNs (e.g. LSTMs)to Temporal/Growing Neural Gases (NG which can handle temporal data) and I would like to know when to use what?

Especially for the use case of classification of temporal data and anomaly detection.

Answer (score 0):

So temporal is a bit outside of my expertise, but the main difference between the two is that RNN is built for time data, ie at any time point, the previous time  is important for predicting the present , and likewise the current point is important for predicting the future. To do this, it finds an optimal collection of data transformation such that it is able to take an input and well predict the outcome. OTOH, neural gas tries to learn a space by covering it in a bunch of vectors and edges, such a graph representation is considered a good approximation of the space.  So both methods create a representation of the space, one in the form of a graph embedded in space, the other as repeated transformations. Now neither of these will automatically do classification or anomaly detection, you have to engineer a system to do these ontop of these algorithms. In general however, if you have time data (especially univariate) , I would stick to RNN and if you have peculiarity shaped spatial data then I'd go for GNN.